# Accessing and Setting Array-Type Properties

Tags: c#, properties

I know that a property has the following form:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int myProperty { get; set; }
}
```

This allows me to do this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.myProperty = 5;
Console.WriteLine(myClass.myProperty); // 5
```

However, **what can I do** so that the following class:

```
class MyOtherClass
{
    public int[,] myProperty
    {
        get
        {
            // Code here.
        }
        set
        {
            // Code here.
        }
    }
}
```

Behaves as follows:

```
/* Assume that myProperty has been initialized to the following matrix:

myProperty = 1 2 3
             4 5 6
             7 8 9

and that the access order is [row, column]. */

myOtherClass.myProperty[1, 2] = 0;

/* myProperty = 1 2 3
                4 5 0
                7 8 9 */

Console.WriteLine(myOtherClass.myProperty[2, 0]); // 7
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your setter code insider `// Code here` ?

Comment: I don't know yet; I have tried everything I know, but only get compile-time errors.

Comment: What errors do you get? I don't see why this shouldn't work..

Comment: You may want to consider using an [`Indexer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) instead of returning the array from the property

Comment: Just use `{ get; set; }` - doesn't that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bypass actually implementing the property and allow the compiler to do it for you, using auto properties;

```
public class Test
{
    // no actual implementation of myProperty is required in this form
    public int[,] myProperty { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.myProperty = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
        Console.WriteLine(t.myProperty[1, 2]);
        t.myProperty[1, 2] = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(t.myProperty[1, 2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just expose the property getter, and use it:

```
class MyOtherClass
{
    public MyOtherClass()
    {
       myProperty = new int[3, 3];
    }

    public int[,] myProperty
    {
        get; private set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers which expose the array directly, you could consider using an [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public class MyIndexedProperty
{
    private int[,] Data { get; set; }

    public MyIndexedProperty()
    {
        Data = new int[10, 10];
    }

    public int this[int x, int y] {

        get
        {
            return Data[x, y];
        }
        set
        {
            Data[x, y] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

So your class may look something like this:

```
public class IndexerClass
{

    public MyIndexedProperty IndexProperty { get; set; }

    public IndexerClass()
    {
        IndexProperty = new MyIndexedProperty();
        IndexProperty[3, 4] = 12;
    }

}
```

Note you'll need to ensure Data is initialized before accessing it - I've done this in the `MyIndexedProperty` constructor.

In use, the result is then:

```
IndexerClass indexedClass = new IndexerClass();
int someValue = indexedClass.IndexProperty[3, 4]; //returns 12
```

The main advantage of this approach is that you hide the actual implementation of how you are storing the values from the caller's use of the set and get methods.

You can also check values before deciding to proceed with the `set` operation e.g.

```
    public int this[int x, int y] {
        get
        {
            return Data[x, y];
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 21) //Only over 21's allowed in here
            {
                Data[x, y] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing with arrays is that you need to set their size before you can use them. For example, you would do something like this:

```
class MyOtherClass
{
    public MyOtherClass(int xMAx, int yMax)
    {
        MyProperty = new int[xMAx, yMax];
    }

    public int[,] MyProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

Your property does not need to expose a set method, because its not the `MyProperty` you're setting, but an internal value of `MyProperty`. For example, MyProperty[1,3].

Answer (score 0):

you can use list instead of array.

```
public Myclass
{
int a{get;set;};
int b{get;set;};
}
```

.....

```
public List<MyClass> myList{get;set;}
```